# Python multiple MySQL Inserts

Tags: python, mysql, api, insert

I'm trying to do multiple inserts on a MySQL db like this:

```
p = 1
orglist = buildjson(buildorgs(p, p))
while (orglist is not None):
    for org in orglist:
        sid = org['sid']
        try:
            sql = "INSERT INTO `Orgs` (`sid`) VALUES (\"{0}\");".format(sid)
            cursor.execute(sql)
            print("Added {0}".format(org['title']))
        except Exception as bug:
            print(bug)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    p += 1
    orglist = buildjson(buildorgs(p, p))
```

However I keep getting a bunch of `2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: 9 Bad file descriptor`

How can I correctly do multiple inserts at once so I don't have to commit after every single insert. Also, can i only do `conn.close()`after the while loop  or is it better to keep it where it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884859/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query) and/or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510114/why-does-mysql-connector-break-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query-e). A couple ideas from the answers to those questions which you might try:

1. Try closing the cursor before closing the connection (`cursor.close()` before `conn.close()`; I don't know if you should close the cursor before or after `conn.commit()`, so try both.)
2. If you're using the Oracle MySQL connector, try using [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) instead; several people said that that fixed this problem for them.

Comment: Switching libraries gave me:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grabber.py", line 57, in <module>
    poporgs()
  File "grabber.py", line 42, in poporgs
    conn.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 718, in commit
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, "COMMIT")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 956, in _execute_command
    raise err.InterfaceError("(0, '')")
pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')

Comment: I see you just accepted this answer, but your last comment suggests that it hadn't been working for you. What changed? You should probably mention (in a comment, if nothing else) what you did differently that made this answer work for you, so that anyone else who finds this question later will know.

Comment: I closed the cursor before closing the connection and I removed `conn.close()` from within the while loop to the very end of the code. Not sure which one of these fixed it but it started working. Also, thanks for the tip, I tend to forget commenting on what actually fixed the issue later on :)